# Convert the decimal digits of a string's Unicode codepoints to binary, reinterpret as decimal, and take the sum

Tags: code-golf, binary, unicode

Yeah... it's confusing. Let me explain it a little better:

1. With a string, get the unicode code points of each letter

   - Let's use `"Hello World!"`.
   - The code points would be `[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33]`
2. Of each digit of the code points, get their binary format

   - Get the binary of `7`, then `2`, then `1`, then `0`, and so on...
   - `['111', '10', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1000', ...]`
3. The binary integers are treated as decimal and summed, and that's the result.

   - Take the integer of the binary (e.g. `'111'` is the integer `111` in decimal; one hundred and one) then sum all of these integers.
   - The result of `"Hello World!"` would be `4389`.

### Test Cases

```
"Hello World!" -> 4389
"Foo Bar!" -> 1594
"Code Golf" -> 1375
"Stack Exchange" -> 8723
"Winter Bash" -> 2988
```

Shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: May I assume input is non-empty?

Comment: As the guts of the problem are the integer/binary manipulations will you accept an answer based on the the common ASCII/Unicode code points

Comment: @tsh yes, there will be a string

Comment: @Graham yes, I will. As long as it works :D

Comment: Can we take input as an array of characters instead of a string? Not sure if that's allowed by default

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
ÇSbO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9zbuv/w@3BSf7//3uk5uTkK4TnF@WkKHK55ecrOCUWKXI556ekKrjn56RxBZckJmcruFYkZyTmpadyhWfmlaQWARUVZwAA)

Get the codepoints, split into digits, convert to binary, sum.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 6 bytes

```
ODFBḌS
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCJPREZC4biMUyIsIsOH4oKsIiwiIixbIlwiSGVsbG8gV29ybGQhXCIsIFwiRm9vIEJhciFcIiwgXCJDb2RlIEdvbGZcIiwgXCJTdGFjayBFeGNoYW5nZVwiLCBcIldpbnRlciBCYXNoXCIiXV0=)

Literally just ord → to digits → flatten → to binary → from decimal → sum

Comment: This makes no sense... how does it work??!

Comment: @12944qwerty added an explanation

Comment: That actually looks really simplistic. Imma need to take a look at the language.

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 62 bytes

```
Tr[FromDigits/@Join@@i@ToCharacterCode@#~i~2]&
i=IntegerDigits
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzLCsIwEEX3fkWM4EoouC8Eq/WxEix0IS6GdEwG0wxMsxDE/npscXe43HN6SB57SGQhuzI3cq@F@z05SkNhLkzRGDINVx4EbEKpuEOzGmncPtYLKs8xoUP5C/kqFFNhXGGU@ugThsCqZQndUm90zax2IDPOEXXk8Jz4lsC@1OFtPUSH09BODZTpOnj9VTn/AA)

-6 bytes from @att

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYzLCsIwEEX3fkWM4EoouC8Eq/WxEix0IS6GdEwG0wxMsxDE/npscXe43HN6SB57SGQhuzI3cq@F@z05SkNhLkzRGDINVx4EbEKpuEOzGmncPtYLKs8xoUP5C/kqFFNhXGGU@ugThsCqZQndUm90zax2IDPOEXXk8Jz4lsC@1OFtPUSH09BODZTpOnj9VTn/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
▒$m▒─àiΣ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RtEkquUDi0ZSGwwsyzy3@/1/JIzUnJ18hPL8oJ0VRiUvJLT9fwSmxCMR0zk9JVXAH6gOyg0sSk7MVXCuSMxLz0lOBAuGZeSWpRUClxRlKAA)

7 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py) by removing the leading `▒` and taking the input as a list of characters: [try it online](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/18l99G0SY@mNBxekHlu8f//0eoe6jrqqUCcA8X5QKwAxOFQdhFUPAWIFdVjuaLV3aAyMJVOQJwIVQlR4QyVTYGaDVLlDhUDmZUGVhUMZJVA9SYDcTZUpSsQV0DFMqDyeUCcDjYNpBPktkyoaAnUjiI01xSDdccCAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
▒         # Convert the (implicit) input-string to a list of characters
 $        # Convert each character to its codepoint integer
  m       # Map over each integer:
   ▒      #  Convert it to a list of digits
    ─     # Flatten the list of lists
     à    # Convert each digit to a binary string
      i   # Convert each string to an integer
       Σ  # Sum them together
          # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 61 bytes

```python
lambda s:sum(int(bin(int(y))[2:])for x in s for y in`ord(x)`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYuxCoAgFAB/5eXkWx2D9v6goYISkwT1iRrk15s23Q13oeSbvKh62qo9nVQnpDE9jhufuTT@Z0FcxbijpggvGA8JupamB0XFXzywhthT3YbwZI6Ilc2XtQQLRasG9gE)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>100</s> <s>97</s> <s>85</s> 79 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 72 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with a `\`.

*Edit: - 5 bytes by @Dominic van Essen with huge thanks and a fair play award.*

```r
function(s)sum(10^(0:31)*!intToBits(unlist(strsplit(c("",utf8ToInt(s)),'')))<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/?fbclid=IwAR0IWJL7VHWOtmZj8oqD2wuj7Ec178yjFRJyRrqLYmiC2jqJeL8_nPngSrY##Nc5dC4IwGIbh837FtAP3hoFf0YzqwOjrOMGzQJar0dob24T@vSno6XXDw2M6setEq7mTqKkF235oHN1ptEljWHhSuxIL6SxttZLWUeuM/SrpKKe@H7ZOsBKvuneAMAgAYBtDJ6h/aZRCUqFRD8@HOVnuSZayfNanEyIpajNxvMqzgQ/4aMgZlZg8Xa8Gv7mav8nxx1@1fjZjZOskHWLVH2xMP2dfY0lyxro/)

Strings, digit split, converting to binary? These are things [R](https://www.r-project.org/) isn't great in. Thank goodness there aren't primes involved in this challenge...

Comment: +1 for 'thank goodness there aren't primes...'

Comment: Probably shouldn't do this, but...  [80 bytes](https://tio.run/?fbclid=IwAR0IWJL7VHWOtmZj8oqD2wuj7Ec178yjFRJyRrqLYmiC2jqJeL8_nPngSrY##Nc5NC4JAFIXhfb9itIVzoyC1cIxqUfS1LmgXiM7k0DRXZq7QvzeF2r4PHI7r1KZTrS1Jo@UefPvm8fzB56s0hkmgLd1wp8nz1hrtiXtyvjGaeFN4krwlJW54sT0ATKMIANYxdIqHZ2kMsjs6UwUhjNlsyxapyEc9HRHZrnD/HC/zxZD3WEl2QqP@Pc2WQ79SUb7Y4VPWhX3KH4osSQe89w@l6@d8/ZMkF6L7Ag) with some funky type conversion...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen - thanks a lot! I didn't know `intToBits` accepts strings, that was clever!

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>87</s> 83 bytes

*Edit: -4 bytes magnanimously thanks to pajonk*

```r
function(s,e=7:0,`/`=Vectorize(function(x,b)x%/%b^e%%b))sum(utf8ToInt(s)/10/2*10^e)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcyxCsIwEADQX9FC4E4CSV0UIbvupW6lJF6hEHMll0Dx5@Mmzg9ebsI@cQ0bi2tLTaGsnEA0ucvN6tnMbqRQOK8fgh/v2uOujPITKeURpb6hluU68CMVEDS9NedTbyfCvx@6O8XIhyfn@Dp22L4)

Works for ASCII characters (codepoint ≤8 bits).  Add 1 byte to handle up to 100-bit codepoints, by changing `7:0` to `99:0`.

**Ungolfed**

```r
g=Vectorize(                    # g is a vectorized helper function
 function(x,b)x%/%b^(7:0)%%b    # that converts x to base b digits
function(s){                    # get the string s
 c=utf8ToInt(s)                 # get the codepoints c
 d=g(c,10)                      # apply g with arg 10 => get decimal digits
 b=g(d,2)                       # apply g with arg 2 => get binary digits
 e=b*10^(7:0)                   # multiply binary digits by powers of 10
 sum(e)                         # return the sum
```

Comment: Probably shouldn't do this, as this will leave me outgolfed... [-4 bytes](https://tio.run/##TcyxCsIwEADQX9FC4E4CSV0UIbvupW6lJF6hEHMll0Dx5@Mmzg9ebsI@cQ0bi2tLTaGsnEA0ucvN6tnMbqRQOK8fgh/v2uOujPITKeURpb6hluU68CMVEDS9NedTbyfCvx@6O8XIhyfn@Dp22L4 "R – Try It Online").

Comment: @pajonk - Great, and thanks.  I'd tried ```Vectorize```, but never thought of replacing the vectorized function for a binary operator.  Really clever.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org/), 62 Bytes

*Thanks to @U12-F̉͋̅̾̇orward*

```py
lambda p:sum(int(f'{int(d):b}')for i in p for d in'%s'%ord(i))
```

[Attempt it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweIc25ilpSVpuhY37XISc5NSEhUKrIpLczUy80o00tSrQVSKplVSrbpmWn6RQqZCZp5CgQKImQJkqqsWq6vmF6VoZGpqQk0pKygC6cnRUPJIzcnJVwjPL8pJUVTS1OSCS7jl5ys4JRahCjrnp6QquOfnpKGIBpckJmcruFYkZyTmpaeiSIUD6dQioEHFGUow2xcsgNAA)

### [Python](https://www.python.org/), 63 Bytes

*Thanks to @att*

```py
lambda p:sum(int(f'{int(d):b}')for i in p for d in str(ord(i)))
```

[Attempt it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweIc25ilpSVpuhY37XMSc5NSEhUKrIpLczUy80o00tSrQVSKplVSrbpmWn6RQqZCZp5CgQKImQJiFpcUaeQXpWhkampqQo0pKygCacrRUPJIzcnJVwjPL8pJUVTS1OSCS7jl5ys4JRahCjrnp6QquOfnpKGIBpckJmcruFYkZyTmpaeiSIUD6dQioEHFGUow2xcsgNAA)

### [Python](https://www.python.org/), 70 Bytes

*Thanks to @Unrelated String*

```py
lambda p:sum(int(f'{int(i):b}')for i in"".join(str(ord(i))for i in p))
```

[Attempt it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY2xCsIwFEV3v-KZpcmgsxRcFKu7QxeXtElsNM0LaSqK-CUuBdF_8m9sUQudDtzDvff-cpdQoG0eZr571kFNZu_E8DITHFxc1SXVNlAVXTtoFme3iCn0oEFbQqYH1JZWwVP0otW9AsfYb-3kfNc1lGykMQgpeiPGhLFRLxJEWHA_DJcoJKzRqEG6DTw_wuqcF9zu5UClLaVvh6qC_N-b5ssP)

### [Python](https://www.python.org/), 77 Bytes

Just a bunch of comprehension

```py
l=lambda p:sum(int(format(int(i),"b"))for i in"".join(str(ord(i))for i in p))
```

[Attempt it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY89DsIwDEZ3TmEyJRIwIyQWED8LE0PntElpwImjNEVwFpYucCduQ0C0Uidb35Of9T1e_h4rcm37bGI5nb8PuERpcyXBL-rGcuMiLylYGX-rEROWMyFSBAaMY2x2JuN4HQOnoBLvEXgh_tKrD99j5GyvEQkyCqjGSTPqwZYIVjIMwzUpDTvCcpAeoywusLkVlXQnPUBZmjokUV2x7ntX7QM)

Comment: [-5 with `format(int(i),"b")` -> `f'{int(i):b}'`. Also, since it isn't recursive, you can drop the `l=` (anonymous function submissions are allowed provided they don't rely on being assigned anyways).](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY2xCsIwFEV3v-KZpcmgsxRcFKu7QxeXtElsNM0LaSqK-CUuBdF_8m9sUQudDtzDvff-cpdQoG0eZr571kFNZu_E8DITHFxc1SXVNlAVXTtoFme3iCn0oEFbQqYH1JZWwVP0otW9AsfYb-3kfNc1lGykMQgpeiPGhLFRLxJEWHA_DJcoJKzRqEG6DTw_wuqcF9zu5UClLaVvh6qC_N-b5ssP)

Comment: @UnrelatedString Thanks! I had just thought the `l=` would be needed since I had seen it on other answers.

Comment: [63 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweIc25ilpSVpuhY37XMSc5NSEhUKrIpLczUy80o00tSrQVSKplVSrbpmWn6RQqZCZp5CgQKImQJiFpcUaeQXpWhkampqQo0pKygCacrRUPJIzcnJVwjPL8pJUVTS1OSCS7jl5ys4JRahCjrnp6QquOfnpKGIBpckJmcruFYkZyTmpaeiSIUD6dQioEHFGUow2xcsgNAA)

Comment: @att Also had wrote that, but was busy so didn't comment yet.

Comment: [-1 byte with modulo string formatting `'%s'%ord(i)` instead of `str(ord(i))`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweIc25ilpSVpuhY37XISc5NSEhUKrIpLczUy80o00tSrQVSKplVSrbpmWn6RQqZCZp5CgQKImQJkqqsWq6vmF6VoZGpqQk0pKygC6cnRUPJIzcnJVwjPL8pJUVTS1OSCS7jl5ys4JRahCjrnp6QquOfnpKGIBpckJmcruFYkZyTmpaeiSIUD6dQioEHFGUow2xcsgNAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal 2.4.1](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 6 bytes

```
Cṅfbvṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=C%E1%B9%85fbv%E1%B9%85&inputs=Hello%20World!&header=&footer=)

```
C      # Charcodes 
 ṅf    # to digitlist
   b   # Each to binary
    vṅ # Each to integer
       # (s flag) Sum
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 74 bytes

```javascript
s=>eval([...s.replace(/./gu,c=>c.codePointAt()),0].join`..toString(2)*1+`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxCsIwEADQX9Gpd1qv6p5CN0fBwUGEhvQaUo5cSWJ/P3Z88Ba72exSWMsl6sR1NjWbnjcr8CGiTIlXsY6ho87/Wmd6R26PTw2xDAUQ2@uXll0jUdFXSSF6uOPpdh6xOo1ZhUnUwwzNg0X08NYk07FBrH8)

Eval abuse ftw!!! -2 bytes thanks to Neil. -1  byte thanks to tsh.

Comment: `[...s.replace(/./gu,c=>c.codePointAt()),0]` saves four bytes, I think?

Comment: @Neil Oh nice! `0,` still needed at the start tho

Comment: Sorry, I was originally working from a previous version, so I hadn't updated it correctly.

Comment: All testcase are ASCII. Must we support higher code points using `/u` flag?

Comment: @tsh I'm not sure, ask on the main question

Comment: `s=>eval([...s.replace(/./gu,c=>c.codePointAt()),0].join\`..toString(2)*1+\`)`

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
ＩΣＩＥ⭆Ｓ℅ι⍘Ｉι²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0F8LwTSzQCC4BSqSDWJ55BaUlEK6Gpo6Cf1FKZl5ijkamJpDjlFicCpUC68wEihlpgoH1//8eqTk5@Qrh@UU5KYpc/3XLcgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
     Ｓ          Input string
    ⭆           Map over characters and join
       ι        Current character
      ℅         Ordinal
   Ｅ            Map over digits
          ι     Current digit
         Ｉ      Cast to integer
        ⍘  ²    Convert to base `2`
  Ｉ             Cast to integer
 Σ              Take the sum
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 11 bytes

```
+//10/2\10\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxdj8tqwzAQRffzFarpoqUoiu2Y2BZ00dLHvossEkMUR7ZFbCmVZLAp7bdXEoU23QzDucwdTlPeERIvSbKLlzsAW35cb+cvXTYIoYnu1Yne7BsmejrRmerb6hPsNnrlfa/QRun+eBXRVZoXlcfPSqEHph2Ks2IV0KM6cvSi+saxdJ0F9mZZfUJPU90x2fKI5uskDcFGSMu1qzBdRJMizysAAp21Z1MSUruq1jUtjL/nP+eLWg3kfeTGCiUNSdKiSDPScottx7EZB6yasB6EZHrGchwOXBtPRyl8Jw7jrNzzgBk2VgvZAlx6InyPvCr8enrkVeGPZ2BOFf57+sCrwoWnp171G20pdyI=)

- `10\` convert input string to a matrix of the digits of its byte representation
- `2\` convert those digits to binary
- `10/` treat those binary numbers as if they were in base 10 (e.g. treat `111` in binary as `111` in base-10)
- `+//` take the sum

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 82 bytes

```
s=>-[...s].flatMap(c=>[...c.codePointAt()+""]).reduce((n,x)=>n-(+x).toString(2),0)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 141 bytes

```lua
s=...t={}u=0 for i=1,#s do v=s:sub(i,i):byte()while v>=1 do n=v%10 v=v//10 b="0"while n>0 do b=(n&1)..b n=n>>1 end u=u+b//10 end end print(u)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JctdCsIwEATgqywVJcGSJq@FzZsn8ARNG22wbKX5URHPHhN9GIaBb5Y45OxRCBHw/Yko4bJu4FC1Ow/TCgl976NhrnW8N69gGX/MbrGQNKoKCNNeyeJS15U22MjmL0jLCgwyOiguhCmWtFZgaYKI8Wh@j7pq7pujwCLPOZ/DMN7g9Bznga72Cw)

**Important** The current version of Lua in TIO is 5.3, this causes the output to be shown with .0 as a floating point number, in Lua 5.4 the output is shown as an integer as expected.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.text.utils math.unicode`, 52 bytes

```
[ [ 1 digit-groups ] map-flat [ >bin dec> ] map Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBBbsIwEEX3PsXHe5AgIJJWyoKqpd10gyoWiIXrTBILY7v2RIJep/fpldIURNXlvDej@TO10uxj/7Z5eV3f4ai4nTCdeNKxsQnaH4OxFC@lYUPp2hJUTBSR6KMjp2@0c0b7ihAiMZ9DNI5xoOjIoiFHUVnzqdh4l3AvhHwmaz22PtpqJAGMMC4xz/JCyCfvsVLxgnFT00UxF/Lhd8Pa21r@V9lyIeSGlT7g8aRb5RqSV5UvZ5mQ2yHLEHilUiv/pmZFnvc77DBFZRrD4yb6LiTsh3PCuLaKB1e@G4eKdHnF@P7Cvl/AqRDsGZPhR5ZU7H8A)

```
                                ! "hi"
[ 1 digit-groups ] map-flat     ! { 4 0 1 5 0 1 }
[ >bin dec> ] map               ! { 100 0 1 101 0 1 }
Σ                               ! 203
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 55 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.chars.sum{|c|c.ord.digits.sum{|d|("%b"%d).to_i}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulgvOSOxqFivuDS3uia5JlkvvyhFLyUzPbMEKpZSo6GkmqSkmqKpV5Ifn1lbW/u/QCEtWskjNScnXyE8vygnRVEp9j8A)

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0DFRi@psiS1WK@4NLe6JrkmWS8lMz2zBMpPqdFQUk1SUk3R1CvJj8@srf3/3yM1JydfITy/KCdFEQA "Ruby – Try It Online") as a full program, or [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0DFRi@psiS1WK@4NLe6JrkmWS8lMz2zBMpPqXHLyU8sUVJNUlJNqa39/98jNScnXyE8vygnRREA "Ruby – Try It Online") if a floating-point sum is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
oV!UYBUs
```

The online interpreter only works with ASCII, because of Octave limitations. For non-ASCII the offline interpreter on MATLAB gives the correct result.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Pz9MMTTSKbT4/391j9ScnHyF8PyinBRFdQA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D8/TDE00im0@L9LyH91j9ScnHyF8PyinBRFdS51t/x8BafEIhDTOT8lVcE9PycNyA4uSUzOVnCtSM5IzEtPBQqEZ@aVpBYBlRZnqAMA).

#### Explanation

```
o    % Implicit input. Convert to double, element-wise. This gives codepoints
V    % Convert to string representation. Gives a row vector of chars
!    % Transposse into a column vector of chars
U    % Interpret each row (that is, each char) as a number
YB   % Convert to binary chars. Gives 3- or 4-column matrix with chars '0', '1', ' '
U    % Interpret each row as a number. Gives a column vector
s    % Sum. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python3.7.4](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-374/), <s>81</s> 79 bytes

```
f=lambda x:sum([int(bin(int(i))[2:])for i in"".join([str(ord(j)) for j in x])])
```

I was able to remove 2 bytes thanks to [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing)'s suggestion.

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##PcsxDsIwDIXhnVOYTPbCQLdKLAyIGzBEGVKFCEdpXLlBKqcPzdLpSf@nt/zqR8rQWrxlP0/Bwzau3xktl4oTF@zLRPY6OoqiwMDFmEuS3exaFUUDJiLomHaEzZGjtmh/RjTPd84CL9EczobodMBDBO5ee2x/)!

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! You can save 2 bytes by removing the spaces between the `)` and the `for`s, and one more by changing `in ""` to `in""`

Comment: Thank you for the insight.

Comment: [74 bytes! -5 bytes by using generators instead of list comprehensions, also instead of `str(ord(j))` I use `'%s'%ord(j)`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRocKquDRXIzOvRCMpMw9MZ2pqRhtZxWqm5RcpZCpk5ikp6WXlA@XUVYvVVfOLUjSywFJZQCmFCk3N/wVFIF1pGkoeqTk5@Qrh@UU5KYpKmppccAm3/HwFp8QikOB/AA). Btw, nice first answer

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 39 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
{+´{0:0;(2|)+10×⌊÷2}¨'0'-˜∾•Fmt¨-@}
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgeyvCtHswOjA7KDJ88J2VqSkrMTDDl/CdlYrijIrwnZWpw7cyfcKoJzAnLcuc4oi+4oCiRm10wqjwnZWpLUB9Cgo+4ouI4p+cRsKo4p+oCiJIZWxsbyBXb3JsZCEiICMtPiA0Mzg5CiJGb28gQmFyISIgIy0+IDE1OTQKIkNvZGUgR29sZiIgIy0+IDEzNzUKIlN0YWNrIEV4Y2hhbmdlIiAjLT4gODcyMwoiV2ludGVyIEJhc2giICMtPiAyOTg4CuKfqQ==)

From what I could muster, recursion was the shortest method to convert the things to proper decimal. Character arithmetic saves a lot as usual.

### Explanation

```
{+´{0:0;(2|)+10×⌊÷2}¨'0'-˜∾•Fmt¨-@}
                                  -@  subtract null character from string
                            ∾•Fmt¨     join all codepoints into a string
                       '0'-˜           subtract zero character to get the digits
   {                  }¨               for each digit:
    0:0;                               if input is 0, return 0
        (2|)+10×⌊÷2                  otherwise,                   
                 ⌊÷2                  recursive call with x // 2
              10×                       multiply with 10
        (2|)+                          add x % 2
 +´                                     sum the result
```

Comment: I understand what everything does except the inner function. A more detailed explanation would be great.

Comment: @DLosc hope the explanation helps. You may want to see [Block headers](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/doc/block.html#block-headers).

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mx`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as an array of characters.

```
c ì x¤
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW14&code=YyDsIHik&input=WyJIIiwiZSIsImwiLCJsIiwibyIsIiAiLCJXIiwibyIsInIiLCJsIiwiZCIsIiEiXQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `d`, 7 bytes

```
Cƛfbvṅ⌊
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJkIiwiIiwiQ8abZmJ24bmF4oyKIiwiIiwiSGVsbG8gV29ybGQhIl0=)

Fun for the whole family.

### Explained

```
Cƛfbvṅ⌊
C      # Character code of each letter
 ƛ     # to each letter code n:
  fb   #   get the binary representation of each digit
    vṅ⌊ #  and convert to int
       # the d flag deep sums the list.
```

Comment: This makes no sense... how does it work??! And how do you get the characters

Comment: @12944qwerty I use the on-screen keyboard provided on the vyxal online interpreter.

Comment: Where is the "d flag"?

Comment: @12944qwerty it's in the header of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
ṁodḋṁodc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxvyUhzu6wXTy////PVJzcvIVwvOLclIUAQ)

(or `ṁȯṁodḋdc` [TIO](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxhPrgUR@ysMd3SnJ////90jNyclXCM8vyklRBAA) or `ṁöṁdmḋdc` [TIO](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxsPbgERK7sMd3SnJ////90jNyclXCM8vyklRBAA), all 8 bytes)

`ṁ`ap & flatten c`o`mbination of `d`ecimal digits & `c`haracter code functions; then `ṁ`ap & sum c`o`mbination of `d`ecimal values from binary `ḋ`igits.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
mc ¬®nA2
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=bWMgrK5uQTI&input=IkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkISI)

```
mc        - codepints
   ¬®nA2  - digits to binary string

-x flag to sum
```

Comment: [7 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=bWMgrK6wpA&input=IkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkISI)

Comment: @Shaggy thanks! I'm gonna leave it as it is because you have your great answer. Happy New year mate cheers!

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>100</s></sup> 89 bytes

```c
m;b;r;d;f(char*s){for(r=0;d=*s++;)for(;d;d/=10)for(m=1,b=d%10;b;b/=2,m*=10)r+=b%2*m;d=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBNb8IwDL3zK7xIlfqFKAVEqyw7DLHtvgOHwaEkKVS0DUoqrRrir69zS6m2RUqU9@znZ5uPD5w3TUH3VFNBU5sfE@0a55IqbWsWUMFc43nUaTEmiAmbBh0o2NTfM2FNA9TuJyz0C7eNaY/trdAtUKnptcnKCookK20HLiPA0xlAJU1lPnbA4ELeZJ4r2CidiwcCPpAXpeA50TewUkLCq8rTDr1XCT/BusYq5UF21AYtpEaBORK40s6kdZX1WfJKipvLfBbFPkwX8Rzf2XLhQ7QMZz6EcRT1Iq5KU/X98aPkJ6n7Drf1OtzW8QrvgqDlLzwjvRp3Anbrm5VC1igLaP99BJN9SZXa946cSU@4A0PB87rs@5p@rQpr3dbVJezoEG/dDEZTu3L@shLZYf7/srPGlNQmW2KZLYHxE1gC8FviaJUPxh@mN4zJXV/6Oro23zzNk4Npxp8/)

Inputs a string and returns the sum of the binary numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 38 bytes

This assumes we are allowed an answer based on the the common ASCII/Unicode code points.

Index origin = 0. Prompts for string:

```
+/⍎¨(⍕¨⊂[1]⍉(4⍴2)⊤⍎¨(⍕⎕av⍳⎕)~' ')~¨' '

⎕av⍳ uses the APL atomic vector to retrieve the ASCII code points.
```

I can only use TIO via Dyalog Classic APL and Dyalog's atomic vector is not identical to that of APL+WIN so that will not work for this solution. However for those who would like to try the integer/binary manipulation via TIO the code below prompts for the integer code points for all the examples given in the question and yields the appropriate sums.

```
+/⍎¨(⍕¨⊂[1]⍉(4⍴2)⊤⍎¨(⍕⎕)~' ')~¨' '
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##RY49CsJAEIX7PcV2Jkhwf5JscgRB8QBiESIRIaCQyiaFhT@BBJvcwCIH8AQ5ylwkzv6gxbCPN@97s9m5DPaXrDwdgrzMquqYT9D16xXcXpKgWm5QMQKPezHNF9B24@BB248DNNct30H79EJoP8KH5v3bIufXMzrz63HAZ0KaTAVRgnLGcRI7nFMpaKKM4jx0G0alJJhmzjepOKapMiGzjB2EYV2JAcWdoysERhKJhqHSFC1lWlAJZo3QFuoCqUs0ggaLrImo@ay@@D8fafAL)

Answer (score 1):

## APOL, 32 bytes

`⊕(⭳(ƒ(i ƒ(Ŀ(t(↶(∋))) I(b(∋))))))`

### Explanation

```
⊕(                Sum (totals all items in a list)
  ⭳(              List flatten (Turns 2d lists into 1d lists)
    ƒ(            List-builder for (returns a list of every return value of the passed instruction during the loop
      i           Input (being iterated through
      ƒ(          List-builder for
        Ŀ(        Cast to int list (Splits a string and returns a list of each character as an integer
          t(      Cast to string
            ↶(    Unicode codepoint
               ∋  For loop item
            )
          )
        )
        I(        Cast to integer
          b(      Binary representation of
            ∋     For loop item
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 61 bytes

```sh
for c (${(s'')1})for d (${(s'')$((#c))})T+=+$[[##2]d]
<<<$[T]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanxPy2/SCFZQUOlWqNYXV3TsFYTJJACF1DR0FBO1tSs1QzRttVWiY5WVjaKTYm1trGxUYkOif2vyZWmoOSRmpOTrxCeX5SToqik8B8A)

Nothing terribly interesting here, except that it saves **1 byte** to do string appending and defer the final `$[sum]` until the last step.

```sh
for char (${(s'')1})                # split into characters
    for digit (${(s'')$((#char))})  # split decimal codepoint into characters
        sum_string+=+$[[##2]digit]  # append "+" and the binary representation to a string
<<<$[sum_string]                    # evaluate that string arithmetically, output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 76 bytes

```hs
e=fromEnum
f s=sum$map(\x->read$(mapM id$"01"<$[0..3])!!(e x-48))$s>>=show.e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc67boMwFAbgPU9xsDzY4qIkEMVIMUOqtB3aKUMGiiormIACOLJBZei7U7tCyni@/9xqYe6ybedZ8kqr7tSP3aoCw83Y4U48yNcUZlqKEhNbfUJTYrTeoAPO11EUF9TziIQpTBil2GQZN7X6ieTciaYHDm7kGx7jcB70Rw@58X0EYQbI94nrxPYSdfYUzbnDX2ICTQ9hvgIg6N1@qOCidFt6KIAkZikN/pNXpeAotNPNLk0WfVGlhDfVVo7j/W7h8yCudzhN11r0N2kztt/GS3Zp@kFqu8vUNtimjNGimP8A)

```hs
..s>>=show.e         - all digits of ascii values 
mapM id$"01"<$[0..3] - combinations of bits
!!(e x-48)           - take at (enum-48) and
map(\x->read$(...)   - read it for every digit
sum                  - sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <strike>69[:(] 68</strike> 65 bytes

```powershell
$args|% t*y|%{+$_-split''|%{$s+=+[Convert]::ToString("$_",2)}};$s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc9NT8JAEAbgc/sr1mYREDCxQCg0TYgNqCeMNeFACKll@NDarTtTxZT97XWDaazcZjLPzJtJxRdI3EEcF3zj5QUP5RaPNUZX38da3uKrDqbxnup13XFsea2FL5JPkLQcjZ5FQHKfbBsWX1ltu6mUy7FQJidA8kMEZB4zxg3TMIxx/pCkGXnWvY4SbC5kvL6w3MkhhYhg7fW6zlC1/8mpEOw2lFV10x/2zpQv1sDuRLypsu6gf8YCCqM3NjlEuzDZQsU6A7t7Zuf7hEDqbNxVoD10HKVds/rfkdVy0@BPgFlM@ttLvmF8dX06ZBqLx8DPkMT77OVVH1mWCaVwZxmd@t/9vywNytoNsigCxBKxDnywylyZyix@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 10 bytes

```
$+TB*J A*a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fRTvESctLwVEr8f///x6pOTn5CuH5RTkpigA)

#### Explanation

```
         a  First command-line argument (the input string)
       A    Get ASCII code
        *   of each character
     J      Join into a single string
  TB        Convert to binary
    *       each character (i.e. digit)
$+          Sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 119 bytes

```php
fn($i)=>array_sum(array_map(fn($y)=>array_reduce(str_split($y),fn($c,$s)=>$c+decbin($s)),array_map(ord,str_split($i))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLCkIhFEXnfoWBAyX7gl5Q9BgEBQ0aXky9KZlHjgb189m9BNUZbfZa@ySX6mSeXCKEtdPaRs68mM4Uono2@X7jn3RTiffs@WVozV1bngs2OQVfeiZ7RUuWO4vpobH67LsmCyF/bwCN/Ft50V0dE6sdUNZypvAShaSH7aFZ7XfjurUhAD0BBjMgawC6UDggSzCWbiC05FiUvtLVQzsVL5acfCwWOym7F6TiIeY6Wr8B)

I mean, the length of this is an abomination but it's all functional, so there's that.  Yes Rasmus, we know, these functions operate on arrays...

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 123 bytes

```javascript
t="toString";c="charCodeAt";x=(s)=>{o=0;for(a in s){e=s[c](a)[t]();for(b in e){o+=parseInt((e[c](b)-48)[t](2));}}return o;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcqxCsIwEADQ3a@ImS5IRcShECKoIDo7OJQOaYy1EnLlEkuh9Nuj7ej83lt3Ohhq2ph1eUpR8Yi3SI2vuTSKm5emEz7sIXLZKwhC7QdUG/lEAs0az4IYrAqFKUGLIpYgZqomsmLAlWo1BXv1EcBOqxLZLp/nVgg5jmTjhzxDOSaDPqCza4c19MAv1jlkdyT3WPLfXfz5GZEdNc2Wvg)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `SB`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
dḞḃN
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPWQlRTElQjglOUUlRTElQjglODNOJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JTIySGVsbG8lMjBXb3JsZCElMjImZmxhZ3M9U0I=)

##### Explanation

```python
dḞḃN  # Implicit input
      # Convert to ordinals
d     # Cast each to digits
 Ḟ    # Flatten the list
  ḃ   # Convert each to binary
   N  # Then cast to integer
      # Sum the list
      # Implicit output
```