# Concatenate characters' indexes in the alphabet in the given numeral system

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion, alphabet

1. Given a word, get the indexes of each letter in the alphabet.

   For example: `uncopyrightable` becomes: `[21, 14, 3, 15, 16, 25, 18, 9, 7, 8, 20, 1, 2, 12, 5]`
2. Convert these indexes to the given numeral system.

   For example, if the radix is `36`, then the array above would become:
   `['l', 'e', '3', 'f', 'g', 'p', 'i', '9', '7', '8', 'k', '1', '2', 'c', '5']`
3. Joining those gives **`le3fgpi978k12c5`**.

Of course you don't have to use arrays.

More examples:

- `dermatoglyphics`, `36` → `45id1kf7cpg893j`
- `undiscoverability`, `8` → `25164112331726522121114112431`
- `superacknowledgement`, `16` → `13151051213bef17c5475d5e14`

---

- Your input will be a word (you decide if it'll be uppercase, lowercase or mixed) and a *valid* radix (2-36).
- You can receive input through any of the standard IO methods.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

([*very similar question here*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/239935))

Comment: You should provide an alphabet for the base conversions. For example, does base 36 use `0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`? What's the maximum base value? 64?

Comment: @caird the index of a letter is the position of the letter in the alphabet - it shoudn't be affected by the base value.

Comment: May the output be in uppercase as well?

Comment: The title says to find the sum of the indexes, but it seems like you just want us to concatenate them

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>13</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ç96-IBlJ
```

-5 bytes thanks to *@ovs*.

With string and integer inputs; and string output. Could be 1 byte less if we can output in uppercase by removing the `l`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cLulma6nU47X//@leSmZxcn5ZalFQKmczJJKLgsA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC6P/D7ZZmuhFOOV7/df5HRyuV5iXnF1QWZaZnlCQm5aQq6RibxeooRCulpBblJpbkp@dUFmRkJhfDxUvzUjKLk/PLUouAhudkllQq6ViAJYpLC4Biydl5@eU5qSnpqbmpeSVKOoZmsbEA).

An alternative for `Ç96-` is `Ask>`, if we take the input as a character-list: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fsTjbztMpx@v//2ilUiUdpTwgTgHiTCAuBuJkIM4H4jIgTgXiIiBOBOIkqJocKF0CxJVKsVwWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVCaPB/x@JsuwinHK//Ov@jo5VK85LzCyqLMtMzShKTclKVdIzNYnUUopVSUotyE0vy03MqCzIyk4vh4qV5KZnFyfllqUVAw3MySyqVdCzAEsWlBUCx5Oy8/PKc1JT01NzUvBIlHUOz2FgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
     # Step 1: Convert the (implicit) input to their 1-based alphabetical index:
Ç    #   Convert the (implicit) input-string to a list of codepoint integers
 96- #   Subtract 96 from each
     #  OR
A    #   Push the lowercase alphabet
 s   #   Swap so the (implicit) input-list is at the top of the stack
  k  #   Get the (0-based) index of each character in the alphabet
   > #   And increase each by 1 to make it a 1-based index

     # Step 2: Convert it to the base of the second input, and output:
IB   #  Convert it to the base of the second input
  l  #  Lowercase all letters, because `B` results in uppercase A-Z
   J #  And join the list together to a string
     #  (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC6P/D7ZZmuhFOOV7/vXT@R0crleYl5xdUFmWmZ5QkJuWkKukYm8XqKEQrpaQW5SaW5KfnVBZkZCYXw8VL81Iyi5Pzy1KLgKbnZJZUKulYgCWKSwuAYsnZefnlOakp6am5qXklSjqGZrGxAA

Comment: @ovs I thought I tried that, but apparently not (correctly).. :S Thanks either way for the -5 bytes!

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 9 bytes

```
ØaiⱮb‘ịØB
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLDmGFp4rGuYuKAmOG7i8OYQiIsIiIsIiIsWyJ1bmNvcHlyaWdodGFibGUiLCIzNiJdXQ==)

-1 byte thanks to caird coinheringaahing

Comment: Obviously, `+1` \$\to\$ `‘` for -1 byte

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing ah, right. I just wanted to get it over with and stop trying to use my broken site on my phone :P

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 36 bytes

```
""<>LetterNumber@#~IntegerString~#2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tcm9CsIwEADg3aeQFJyyqFAcVLoKIoKjdEjS43qYn3K9KF366rFjtw@@YKSHYIScKXgpSp2vdxABfuRggZtqvkUBBH4JU8S5OuzKc5FsG3yrHF0aJibsxVgPSh/rdrPujkaXvsDGkieZlD6tf8zDUu4T089DhxAgitL7ui3lDw)

87-36 bytes from @att

Comment: `IntegerString` exists.

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##Tcm9CsIwEADg3aeQFJyyqFAcVLoKIoKjdEjS43qYn3K9KF366rFjtw@@YKSHYIScKXgpSp2vdxABfuRggZtqvkUBBH4JU8S5OuzKc5FsG3yrHF0aJibsxVgPSh/rdrPujkaXvsDGkieZlD6tf8zDUu4T089DhxAgitL7ui3lDw) since `IntegerString` is `Listable`

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
⭆θ⍘⊕⌕βιＩη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaBTqKDglFqdCBDQ885KLUnNT80pSUzTcMvNSNJJ0FDI1NXUUnBOLSzQyNIHA@v//0ryUzOLk/LLUosSkzJzMkkoui/@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 θ          First input
⭆           Map over characters and join
    ⌕       0-indexed index of
      ι     Current character
     β      In lowercase alphabet
   ⊕        Incremented i.e. 1-indexed
  ⍘         Convert to string base
        η   Second input
       Ｉ    Cast to integer
```

When given an integer base, the string base conversion uses the appropriate prefix of `0-9a-zA-z`.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 53 bytes

Expects `(string)(radix)`.

```javascript
s=>r=>Buffer(s).map(c=>s+=(c%32).toString(r),s='')&&s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc5LbsMgFIXheVcRRWoCauv08rDTAR50C10B4VUSDBbgVFm9S6qOcodH@j/ds7zKorKf61tM2qxWrEWMWYyfi7Umo4K7Sc5IibG8CKSeKcFdTV81@@hQxq9F7Pd4tyurSrGkYLqQHLJoq02eZE0u3OZvr8oWI9pjvPm7w2HDuNdwsYOa3fGDnp8e6iVqX1S6mixPPvh6a/3xP2814dAzAEIpDKTnhAABgPvCKDxaZZkboy4x/QSjnZlMrI2D@zvNAgoc3nkT6MlYGBRnA9fcAFt/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 20 bytes

```
mȯc+48?+7I>9ṁȯB⁰%32c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fE@mRtEwt7bXNPO8uHOxtPrHd61LhB1dgo@f///8Zm/1NSi3ITS/LTcyoLMjKTiwE)

No easy `0-9A-Z` built into [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), so 12 bytes used to roll our own.

Main part: get the digit values in the given base

```
ṁȯ              # map and flatten across input string
       c        # get the character code
    %32         # modulo 32 (so A=1, B=2, ...)
  B⁰            # convert to digits in base given by input number
```

Helper function: convert digit values to 0,1,2,...9,A,B,C,...,Y,Z

```
mȯ              # map over all digit values
      ?   >9    # if it's bigger than 9
       +7       # add 7
         I      # otherwise leave unchanged;
   +48          # then add 48
  c             # and convert to corresponding ASCII character
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 73 bytes

```java
s->r->s.chars().mapToObj(c->r.toString(c%32,r)).reduce("",String::concat)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBNS8QwEEDP218RCkIibUAXRHa1R8GDeFhv4iGbpN1080UyqRTZ316jLb3uXIaZN28GpmcDq3txnpTxLgDqc00TKE3bZDkoZ@ntvvDpqBVHXLMY0RtTFv0UKMfSj8Agp8EpgUym@ABB2e7zC7HQRZKHNy/LtqcZVWv9akF2MlRzv2lQ@zzFugl1Eyk/sRAxoYb5D/d@7DHPgIKbZzG/2d5XgRAapEhc4rJctux23FnOgEz7YnMYI0hDXQLqMwRtcUuZ93rEpZDBMHCdHv1J8ViSBWwfCLmiJitU5G6QgR2VVjCu8uNVNyafNX627ltL0UkjLaz63f/tv@9eisv0Cw)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 89 bytes

```
\(x,y)Reduce(paste0,sapply(el(strsplit(x,"")),\(z)cwhmisc::int2B(grep(z,letters),y))[1,])
```

With `R < 4.1`, `\` needs to be replaced with `function` resulting in a total of 104 bytes.

-5 bytes thanks to @pajonk.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcyxDgIhDIDhVzFMbdJBHRl9BFfjQLB3kiA2tMTjXh6Zbv@/v46xtBItfQts1PHOrxYZJKjxmTSI5A6cQa2q5GQzcg6RDrRj/L0/SaP3qdj1BmtlgZ1Omc24Ks4pPi70xDH@)

Comment: Nice to see one more R golfer! You may find it useful to check the tips page for golfing in R: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4024/tips-for-golfing-in-r (for example use `el(...)` instead of `...[[1]]` or `Reduce(paste0,...)` instead of `paste(...,collapse="")`). It would also be nice to have a link to an online interpreter, so anyone can check the answer, see for example https://tio.run/#r.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
#`nUc)sV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=I2BuVWMpc1Y&input=InVuY29weXJpZ2h0YWJsZSIKMzY)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 12 bytes

```
C96-kr⁰Ẏ$vτ∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=C96-kr%E2%81%B0%E1%BA%8E%24v%CF%84%E2%88%91&inputs=undiscoverability%0A8&header=&footer=)

A bit messy but it works.

```
C            #  Charcodes
 96-         # -96
    kr⁰Ẏ     # 0-9a-zA-Z sliced to input length
        $vτ  # Convert each to that base
           ∑ # Sum the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>57</s></sup> 56 bytes

```c
f(s,r)char*s;{for(;*s;*s+=*s<10?49:56,++s)*s-=65,*s%=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHrjppAFP6/TzElMUHAdJGLWtY2CixLZZV4aWOqaeg47JoiEoamtsZXX/YMF0O2hUDmfPNdzszBnSeM8zzkqZS28XOQCtQ4h8eUN2AhUHEo0Dv59pM6@KDpkijStkA7Q12TBNoapsYl38cZOgT7mG@j8w2Cp/BAGaEZ/bZFQ3TmVlNz5q/nrvOwHI09m5MQZ9nzx9Fy5nhr/8E1FwxaTS13Yc6@2PPR2PXc5ZqBi5UPtTmZzr56tuXYj/Z0yV2MIogls5jvaZmj6BJiX19Csl5xymbIKSE4I7uqH89W7h3fHfT6E7lraixH1VxLntz3TN/pD5TPDNJ0VVaUnq515a6swstARXOgVsY2UDW1p1mardb94GNMsyoRPxP8k1SNcZuT3d2cBiZ8RVqjVmo1XDni2ZH28Y6cQHZrVMs7RPd/yTHk62O031eAcEUMJIoFu55CYxLgVU6jIGyN6z5Li2CXZmlEYj5rG2@kP36FIewfgig6Yj5CIpIbHJDh5A/PSBJqiplvWqXCcN7GhpUk/SePgOg6q/91mwSUAucdiz4klQ9p@CQp0EKe23AtuoGrbu1Q5yMqKwS/GLAMoiVUaus5MeNt5XO5ueQvOIyCJ5p3fr8C)

*Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*

Inputs an uppercase string.
Maps the string such that `A` -> `1`, `B` -> `2`, \$\dots\$, `J` -> `A`, `K` -> `B`, \$\dots\$ modulus radix \$r\$.